# Subtracting from different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to subtract the `startdate` from the `enddate` on different rows, but only for the same code.

For example:

- I want to do `startdate` in row 2 for `C002 (2012-07-01)` minus `enddate` in row 1 for `C002 (2012-06-30)`.

  - The result should be 1 (day) for row 2. No data should be in row 1.
- Row 4 should show 1 (day) as well.

How can I go about doing this?

```
row   code      startdate                 enddate
1     C002      2011-07-01 00:00:00.000    2012-06-30 00:00:00.000
2     C002      2012-07-01 00:00:00.000    2013-06-30 00:00:00.000
3     C003      2011-07-01 00:00:00.000    2012-06-30 00:00:00.000
4     C003      2012-07-01 00:00:00.000    2013-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: sounds like you want LEAD() but can you show an expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(row),code,datediff(day,max(startdate),min(enddate)) as ouputtt
from table
group by 
code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
Select x.code, y.startdate-x.enddate
From table1 x left outer join table1 y on
X.code=Y.code
Where
X.enddate<y.startdate
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query, which adds the requested value as an additional column:

```
select row, code, startdate, enddate,
       datediff('d', lag(enddate) over (partition by code order by row1), startdate) df
from   mytable
```